# Moving a window to the side doesn't resize it on the inside of multiple monitors

Tags: windows, display

You know how in Windows 8 when you move a window to the side it will position the window so it takes up half the screen?  The two monitor display I am using doesn't do that on the inside.  So if I do it on the outside of the right monitor and the outside of the left monitor it works, but not in the middle.  Is there a way to get it to work there, too?

Answer (score 0):

Use the key combination of Windows+LeftArrow or Windows+RightArrow. This will move the window left or right across your monitors, snapping the window in place at each step.

[Source](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-snap-windows-side-side-dual-multi-monitor-setup)

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the Windows Snap feature (also known as "Aero Snap" in Windows 7).  When you have a two monitor display, windows essentially treats both monitors as one, so the "inside" of both monitors is like the "middle" of a single monitor.
    **EDIT: I'm wrong about this - please see the post by Brandon Mitchell for a great tutorial on how to do this**.  *I stand by my recommendations below though :)*

You could use a 3rd party solution to accomplish the "middle snap" you are trying to achieve.  There are many options, but [This](https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/2rn775/best_tiled_window_manager_for_windows/) reddit post has a pretty good list of what's available.  Search for "Windows Tiling Software" if you'd like more options.

By the way, if you have Windows 10, you can also use 2×2 snapping and vertical snap features [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/198230/how-to-use-snap-assist-and-2x2-snap-on-windows-10/) is a good article on using them, and I would be remiss if I didn't mention Virtual Desktops as a potential solution.  I create a virtual desktop for each "group" of application windows I'm using for a particular task.  For example, Virtual Desktop 1 will have all of my programming applications, while virtual desktop has email & other communications.  Switching between them is a breeze with the shortcuts - much faster than have to click around. Good luck!